# Css on clickable element (*[onclick]:hover)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I want to use to style my clickable element (javascript function onclick), when they hovered.
So far I have this :

```
*[onclick]:hover{
    background-color: red ;
    color: blue;
}
```

It works fine for most of my elements as you can see :

```js
document.getElementById('C').onclick =  function(){alert('I am clickable too !')}
```

```css
div {
    background-color: green ;
    margin : 2px
}
*[onclick]:hover{
    background-color: red ;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="A" onclick='alert("A")'>Click me ! A</div>
<div id="B" onclick='alert("B")'>Click me ! B</div>
<div id="notAclickableElement" >Don't click me :( Z</div>
<div id="C" >Click me ! C</div>
<div id="D" onclick='alert("D")'>Click me ! D</div>
```

But it only work for element where the onclick function is written in the Html page, and not added via Javascript.
Is there a way to properly select all clickable elements ?

Comment: What is your criteria for making the element a clickable one? You should add one class on them based on that criteria, and then declare the styles for that class in your css file.

Answer (score 1):

The browser know a handful of elements that can be clicked by default, like the `<a>` and `<button>` elements. It is usually a good practice to use these elements if you want the user the click them, as they require little work to modify.

Other than that you could just add a class to the elements which to target them with as there is not a selector for an element that can be clicked.

However, it is a good practice to add a `tabindex` attribute to the elements that can be clicked as it makes them focusable. Users without a mouse (they exist) can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to cycle through the clickable elements and click them with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. The elements mentioned in the first paragraph already incorporate this natively. With `<div>` elements you'll have to add this behavior manually.

The example below targets all clickable elements with a class and adds the `:focus` selector for the focussed styles.

```js
document.getElementById('C').onclick = function() {
  alert('I am clickable too !')
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 2px
}

.clickable:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}

.clickable:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="A" class="clickable" onclick='alert("A")' tabindex="0">Click me ! A</div>
<div id="B" class="clickable" onclick='alert("B")' tabindex="0">Click me ! B</div>
<div id="notAclickableElement">Don't click me :( Z</div>
<div id="C" class="clickable" tabindex="0">Click me ! C</div>
<div id="D" class="clickable" onclick='alert("D")' tabindex="0">Click me ! D</div>
```

Comment: <a> and <button> are cool, but they are only useful to open new pages. But if mostly use onclick to trigger javascript function.

Comment: While the `<a>` is mainly for navigation, `<button>` is not. It only has default behavior in a form, but that too can be disabled with a single line of JS.

Comment: It is a very common practice to use the elements mentioned above and bind your own behavior to them with JavaScript. It's semantics and that makes your document more meaningful. Otherwise every element could just be a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just remove the `[onclick]` in the CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('C').onclick =  function(){alert('I am clickable too !')}
```

```css
div {
    background-color: green ;
    margin : 2px
}
*:hover{

    background-color: red ;
    color: blue;


}
```

```html
<div id="A" onclick='alert("A")'>Click me ! A</div>
<div id="B" onclick='alert("B")'>Click me ! B</div>
<div id="notAclickableElement" >Don't click me :( Z</div>
<div id="C" >Click me ! C</div>
<div id="D" onclick='alert("D")'>Click me ! D</div>
```

However, that also changed the background too, so we can designate a specific class to the divs like so:

```js
document.getElementById('C').onclick =  function(){alert('I am clickable too !')}
```

```css
div {
    background-color: green ;
    margin : 2px
}
.hoverme:hover{

    background-color: red ;
    color: blue;


}
```

```html
<div class="hoverme" id="A" onclick='alert("A")'>Click me ! A</div>
<div class="hoverme" id="B" onclick='alert("B")'>Click me ! B</div>
<div class="hoverme" id="notAclickableElement" >Don't click me :( Z</div>
<div class="hoverme" id="C" >Click me ! C</div>
<div class="hoverme" id="D" onclick='alert("D")'>Click me ! D</div>
```

Designating the hover to a single class is much more efficient, because you can define different hover effects for different things. All you have to do is add `class="hoverme"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .class in CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('C').onclick =  function(){alert('I am clickable too !')}
```

```css
div {
    background-color: green ;
    margin : 2px
}
*[onclick]:hover{
    background-color: red ;
    color: blue;
}
.click {
  background-color: green;
}

.click:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="click" id="A" onclick='alert("A")'>Click me ! A</div>
<div id="B" onclick='alert("B")'>Click me ! B</div>
<div class="click" id="notAclickableElement" >Don't click me :( Z</div>
<div class="click" id="C" >Click me ! C</div>
<div class="click" id="D" onclick='alert("D")'>Click me ! D</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].id !== 'notAclickableElement') {
        x[i].setAttribute('class', 'clickclass');
    }
}

document.getElementById('C').addEventListener("click", hoverMe);
function hoverMe() {
    alert('I am clickable too !')
}
```

```css
div {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 2px
}

.clickclass:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="A" onclick='alert("A")'>Click me ! A</div>
<div id="B" onclick='alert("B")'>Click me ! B</div>
<div id="notAclickableElement">Don't click me :( Z</div>
<div id="C">Click me ! C</div>
<div id="D" onclick='alert("D")'>Click me ! D</div>
```

Comment: Okay your edit works, but it effects all div. I'm looking for a way to only select clickable element. Alos, why did you change the Javascript code ?

Comment: I edited the code. Please try again. I hope it works for you now